# Mapbox SDK v10: How to define offline region geometry with rectangle shape

Tags: android, ios, maps, mapbox, offline

Subject: tileRegionLoadOptions, Downloading offline maps

Previous to SDK v10, offline regions were rectangular in nature: we would specify simply the coordinates of the North-East point and the coordinates of the South-West point and that was it.
Now, on V10, Mapbox introduced the concept of region geometries, so it seems that an offline region can be defined various shapes, not just rectangles.
The question is: how to define a rectangle on the new API? There are no examples and in the documentation Mapbox include one very specific case of a single point, as it seems:

Android:

```
val tileRegionLoadOptions = TileRegionLoadOptions.Builder()
.geometry(TOKYO)
.descriptors(listOf(tilesetDescriptor))
.metadata(Value(TILE_REGION_METADATA))
```

iOS:

```
let tileRegionLoadOptions = TileRegionLoadOptions(geometry: Geometry(coordinate: tokyoCoord), descriptors: [], metadata: metadata, : true)
```

For example consider that we want to specify an offline region as a rectangle defined by:

```
(long/lat)  
-8.226762635, 41.95699448
-8.244230531, 41.92861862
-8.244230531, 41.95699448
-8.226762635, 41.92861862
```

How can we code this on the new geometry property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, you can do this with:

```
Polygon.fromLngLats(listOf(points))
```

Or with any other class which implements `Geometry`, you can find such classes by searching for `Implementing classes` in Android Studio:

[image]

More complete example:

```
private fun getDownloadOptions(points: List<Point>) = TileRegionLoadOptions.Builder()
    .geometry(Polygon.fromLngLats(listOf(points)))
    .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for the answer for how to do this on iOS, you can do it like this.

First, define the coordinates of the four corners of your rectangle like this:

```
let coordinates = [
    LocationCoordinate2D(latitude: bounds.southwest.latitude, longitude: bounds.southwest.longitude),
    LocationCoordinate2D(latitude: bounds.northeast.latitude, longitude: bounds.northeast.longitude),
    LocationCoordinate2D(latitude: bounds.southwest.latitude, longitude: bounds.northeast.longitude),
    LocationCoordinate2D(latitude: bounds.northeast.latitude, longitude: bounds.southwest.longitude)
]
```

(Here I'm reading them from a `CoordinateBounds` object.)

Then use this to instantiate a `Polygon`:

```
let polygon = Polygon([coordinates])
```

Now you can use this polygon in your `TileRegionLoadingOptions`:

```
let tileRegionLoadOptions = TileRegionLoadOptions(
    geometry: Geometry(polygon),
    // etc.
)
```